# Need a select statement to join two tables that are connected by a junction table, but one has null values

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables:
Artist, Song, and song_artist (junction table).

I need to list the titles of all songs and their respective artists, even the songs without artists, but not artists without songs.

`Artist` table columns: artist_id, artist_name.

`Song` table columns: song_id, title, minutes, seconds, sales, genre_id.

`song_artist` table columns: song_id, artist_id

Please advise. Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

If you want all songs, you want a `left join`.  The first table should be `songs`:

```
select s.*, a.artist_name
from songs s left join
     artist_songs ars
     on ars.song_id = s.song_id left join
     artists a
     on ars.artist_id = a.artist_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have not matching between song and song_artist then you could use LEFT JOIN

```
   select a.artists, 
          s.song_id
   FROM artist a
   INNER JOIN song_artist sa ON a.artist_id = sa.artist_id
   LEFT JOIN Song s ON s.song_id = sa.song_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `LEFT` join of `Song` to `Song_Artist` and `Artist`:

```
select s.title, a.artist_name
from song s 
left join song_artist sa on sa.song_id = s.song_id
left join artist a on a.artist_id = sa.artist_id
```